# Strange characters when exporting database

Tags: php, sql, character-encoding, phpmyadmin, notepad++

I'm writing a quick script to remove duplicates from the database. I exported the database from phpMyAdmin before starting just in case I mess something up and I noticed some weird characters in a handful of rows. I'm wondering what might have caused this? The records are uploaded from a plaintext file delimited by bars ("|"). I'm not the one uploading the plaintext files so I don't know if the original files are being altered before upload/import but I use nothing but Notepad++. I know that the original flat file will never contain anything like this.

Also, I did a SELECT * FROM `records` WHERE `case_number` = 'Â š“Ïœ“5ø.lÕ''éíÿ" ÒŒ  qDþ’' and it showed me the record, so it's not my text editor. These are actual rows in the DB.

Can anyone offer a suggestion as to what this might be, what might have caused it and how I might be able to fix it?

I welcome any suggestions at all. Thanks for looking.

**EDIT:**

My DB collation is set to latin1_general_ci

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried viewing this as UTF-8? Encoding -> Encoding in UTF-8. If the sql dump is messed up, and the mysql data is messed up, last thing you can try is changing some datatypes of the columns in your database.

Comment: @DavidChen when viewing as UTF-8 the normal looking characters turn into jibberish as well.

Comment: Your db collation may be different with the `case_number`,`wild1` columns collation. if they have `varchar` type

Comment: @Amir thanks I didn't realize I could do that. However they are all set to `latin1_general_ci`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems with to be with the `collation` that is set for your database. For eg, suppose you upload a totally proper looking file into MySQL, however if say your collation for the field(s) into which the data is ultimately saved is in, suppose, Chinese. Then when you try to retrieve and render content, it will show encoding issues.

Also try to view the content in PhpMyAdmin and see how it looks.

Comment: I would say you're on the right track, however, lines 3490 to 3497 look fine. Rows after that look empty, so it could have been an initial loading error from the start.

Comment: I have seen this issue happen in random lines when the collation screws up. Though I agree that it might be an initial loading error.

Comment: @Raidenace Thanks for the suggestion. I don't know much about databases, but i see it is currently set to  latin1_general_ci. Should I change to ascii or something? I've posted screenshots.

Comment: latin1_general_ci should not cause this issue...at this point, I am forced to ask if there is anyway you can get ahold of the uploaded file?

Comment: @Raidenace The files are generated by Pacer.gov. They're bankruptcy cases. Here's a pastebin of the contents. http://pastebin.com/2ZGeiQky

Comment: @Raidenace if you'd like to see the actual file itself I can upload it somewhere.

Comment: Your file looks ok, this is only having English Chars, right? Couple more questions - was this working correctly previously and then one fine day started showing weird characters?

Comment: @Raidenace I can't be sure when these rows started doing this. As far as I know it's working fine right now, these records appear isolated. I just want to catch the problem before anything else happens.

Comment: In which case, I think the encoding in the file that was uploaded might have been off...